# Drupal: create content in popup/lightbox?

Tags: drupal

In Drupal, is there a way to create new content (based on a content type that uses CCK) in a popup or lightbox or similar technique?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two worlds that I know of:

http://drupal.org/project/popups_reference which uses http://drupal.org/project/popups

and

http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships which uses http://drupal.org/project/modalframe

Both of these are about creating the node in a modal in order to reference it via a node reference field. There might be ones for more general purposes, or you could probably adapt one of those. I've been enjoying noderelationships lately. Haven't tried the other recently.

Answer (score 3):

The projects sprugman refers to are useful when you need to create a referenced node while you're adding another node. If you simply want to make the /node/add/[contenttype] link to open in a lightbox, try the [Lightbox2 module](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2).

Answer (score 2):

There is a great module in Drupal [automodal](http://drupal.org/project/automodal) that works with [Modal Frame API](http://drupal.org/project/modalframe). What you need to do is simply add a new class 'automodal' to your links... and the magic is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another one is the [Modal Nodereference](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_noderef) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... turns the nodereference widget into a modal popup allowing new linked nodes to be created on the fly. Because it uses an iframe, it should support even Javscript and file uploads within the sub-node.
>
> The big feature: It should work with editors, image fields, and all of those other JavaScripting things. We built it precisely to meet those needs. We started with modalframe, instead of one of the other popup libraries, because we knew that we could make this work with TinyMCE, CKEditor, and ImageField -- libraries that have difficulties dealing with other popup APIs.
>
> It depends on the [Automodal](https://www.drupal.org/project/automodal) module, as well as the excellent [Modal Frame API](https://www.drupal.org/project/modalframe) module.